# Why is the list only adding certain numbers?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to compile a list of int by asking the users for inputs. However, the code, for some reason, only adding even numbers to the list. Also, the while loop only stops when I input 999 the second time. The code is as follow:

```
import java.util.*;

public class hw3 {
  public static void main (String args[]) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> pre = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while (input.nextInt() != 999) {
      pre.add(input.nextInt());
    }
  }
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Please point out my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nextInt()` is getting called twice, once before the loop and then inside the while loop.

you need to do something like this:

```
  public static void main (String args[]) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> pre = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int in; 
    while ((in = input.nextInt()) != 999) {
      pre.add(in);   
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

You're calling input.nextInt() twice for each iteration of the loop.

Just call it once, caching the result and use it when adding to your array instead.